# How to determine the locale within alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have a java class represents the list of value and i need to enforce the locale within it.

How can i determine the locale ?

The following class displays Constraint value/label for a content model.

```
package com.ds.ui.constraints;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;  
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.constraint.ListOfValuesConstraint;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.util.BeanUtil;

public class PositionPermissionsConstraints extends ListOfValuesConstraint
    implements Serializable {

public void initialize(){
    LOG.debug("PositionPermissionsConstraints Initializer");
    super.setCaseSensitive(false);
    preparePermissionList();
}

public void preparePermissionList(){
    ResourceBundle bundle = null;   
    if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null){
        if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale() != null)
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BeanUtil.RESOURECE_BUNDLE,
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale());
    }
    else
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BeanUtil.RESOURECE_BUNDLE);

    List<String> av = new ArrayList<String>();
    av
    .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
            CREATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(CREATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION));
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                UPDATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(UPDATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                DELETE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(DELETE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                CREATE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(CREATE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION));            
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                MANAGE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(MANAGE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION));
    av
    .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
            CREATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(CREATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                UPDATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(UPDATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                DELETE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(DELETE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                MANAGE_POSITION_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(MANAGE_POSITION_PERMISSION));         
    av
        .add(PositionPermissionsConstraints.
                ASSIGN_POSITION_TO_USER_PERMISSION);
    this.allowedLabels
    .add(bundle.getString(ASSIGN_POSITION_TO_USER_PERMISSION));
    this.setAllowedValues(av);
    this.setAllowedLabels(allowedLabels);   
}

public List<SelectItem> prepareSelectItemsList(){
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BeanUtil.RESOURECE_BUNDLE);
    List<SelectItem> selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for(String value : getAllowedValues()){
        SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(value,bundle.getString(value));
        selectItems.add(selectItem);
    }
    return selectItems;
}

private static final String CREATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION = "CREATE_ORGANIZATION";
private static final String UPDATE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION = "UPDATE_ORGANIZATION";
private static final String DELETE_ORGANIZATION_PERMISSION = "DELETE_ORGANIZATION";
private static final String CREATE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION = "CREATE_ROOT_POSITION";
private static final String MANAGE_ROOT_POSITION_PERMISSION = "MANAGE_ROOT_POSITION";
private static final String CREATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION = "CREATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION";
private static final String UPDATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION = "UPDATE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION";
private static final String DELETE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION_PERMISSION = "DELETE_SUBORDINATE_POSITION";
private static final String MANAGE_POSITION_PERMISSION = "MANAGE_POSITION";
private static final String ASSIGN_POSITION_TO_USER_PERMISSION = "ASSIGN_POSITION_TO_USER";

private List<String> allowedLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PositionPermissionsConstraints.class);

public List<String> getAllowedLabels() {
    return allowedLabels;
}
public void setAllowedLabels(List<String> allowedLabels) {
    this.allowedLabels = allowedLabels;
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a WebScript, then [I18NUtil](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/I18N) is what you want. The method `public static Locale getLocale()` on it will return the locale for the currently running webscript

Comment: Thanks, What about using Java Foundation API

Comment: I'm trying to develop a constraints that have a value and labels and that labels is translated into the logged in locale.

Comment: I repeat the question, what is triggering your code to run? If it's being run as a webscript then you know the user's current locale (from the request from their browser), but if you're running async then you'll need to do something to store the user's last seen locale so you have it available to you (Alfresco doesn't track this between requests)

Comment: My code is triggering by using an alfresco custom generator, at all cases i think that i find the solution where the generator createComponenet which in turn invoke  constraint.prepareSelectItemsList() which in turn use the I18NUtil.getLocale() to prepare a list of select items. Thanks